# deleting div using previousSibling.remove() in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is the code,

```
function addChoice(title,qs,first){
    choice = choice + 1;
    var container = document.getElementById("listingC");
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = "checkbox";
    checkbox.name = "choice";
    checkbox.value = choice;
    checkbox.id = title+'_'+qs+'_'+choice;

    var text = document.createElement('textarea');
    text.className = "ch";
    text.id = title+'_'+qs+'_'+choice+'_value';

    var answerText = document.createTextNode(" Correct Answer ");
    var del = document.createElement('input');
    del.className="delBtn";
    del.type="button";
    del.value="delete";
    var clear = document.createElement('div');
    clear.className="clear";
    container.appendChild(text);
    container.appendChild(checkbox);
    container.appendChild(answerText);
    if(first){
    }else{
        container.appendChild(del);
    }

    var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("delBtn");
    for(var i  = 0; i < btns.length;i++){
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
            var ch = e.target;
            var correctText = ch.previousSibling;
            var checkboxS = correctText.previousSibling;
            var textareaS = checkboxS.previousSibling;
            ch.remove();
            correctText.remove();
            checkboxS.remove();
            textareaS.remove();
        }, false);
    }
    init2(text);
}
```

This code, dynamically creates elements Textarea, Checkbox, TextNode, and a Button. If a user click the button it must delete the elements.

For example,

```
<textarea class="ch" style="height: 57px;"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2">
Correct Answer
<textarea class="ch" style="height: 57px;"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="3">
Correct Answer
<textarea class="ch" style="height: 57px;"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="4">
Correct Answer
<input class="delBtn" type="button" value="delete">
<textarea class="ch" style="height: 57px;"></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="5">
Correct Answer
<input class="delBtn" type="button" value="delete">
```

The first 2 Textarea, chekcbox textnode, are not dynamically created and dont have a delete button. 
If the user click the first delete button, it must delete the 3 previous siblings.

It is working but have an error. 
TypeError: correctText is null
var checkboxS = correctText.previousSibling;

Comment: Every time you call `addChoice` it will add an additional `click` handler to all the old delete buttons. You should only add a handler to the new delete button that you just added.

Comment: Why not wrap the associated elements and textNodes together in a [`<fieldset>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset), and have the delete button delete that parent?